# How do I make TextEdit open documents in a new window in Sonoma?

Tags: macos, textedit, sonoma, document-management

I've just got a new iMac, running Sonoma. My old iMac was running Catalina.

When I open an .rtf document while another document is also open in TextEdit, it opens the second document in a new tab in the existing window, rather than in a new window like it did in Catalina. I'd prefer to open documents in a new window by default.

I can't see anything in the TextEdit menus or settings dialogue to control this. Is it possible to change this behaviour, or is this yet another feature Apple have taken away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *System Settings*, navigate to *Desktop and Dock* and check the setting under “Windows” ***Prefer tabs when opening documents***.

Most probably you have set it to “Always”, so I recommend to change it to “In Full Screen”

Comment: That's solved it, thanks very much!